# global variable giving incorrect output

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

I have declared a variable globally and it is getting its value from page load function but the variable is not returning the value correctly in the button clicked function.

```
        string id = "1";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        id = "3";
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         label.text = id;
        }
```

Output
label.text = "1"
why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

well when you click postback runs and assigns value to 3, so you will get only 3 unless you do the page load assignment when it is not postback

```
 string id = "1";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
                id = "3";
        }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         label.text = id;
        }
```